# Java: Spring boot Tomcat Access Logs are not created at Tomcat Start

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, spring-boot

I want to access tomcat logs of my service which is build in spring boot having embedded tomcat 8 in it.
I have written following code in `bootstrap.yml` of my service.

```
server:
  port: 8320 
  context-path: /luggage-service
  tomcat:
   accesslog:
      directory: "/var/log/tomcat"
      enabled: true
      pattern: "{\"Hostname\":\"%h\", \"Logical username from identd\":\"%l\", \"Remote user\":\"%u\", \"Date&Time\":\"%t\", \"HTTP Status code\":\"%s\", \"Bytes Sent\":\"%b\", \"Time taken to process the request\":\"%D\", \"Local IPAdderss\":\"%A\", \"Local port\":\"%p\", \"Time taken to Commit the Request\":\"%F\", \"Request Method:%m User SessionID\":\"%S\", \"Requested URL path\":\"%U\", \"Local ServerName\":\"%v\"}"
```

When i build and run my service, then a file `"access_log.yyyy-mm-dd.log"` is created and when i hit calls of my service,then no logs are created in log file.
Logs are created when i stop my tomcat.
What changes do i need to do in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try:

```
server.tomcat.accesslog.buffered=false
```

Comment: When I am adding this property buffered, a warning is shown that metadata property doesn't exit. So i created additional-spring-configuration-metadata,json in META-INF to add this property in metadata. Now warning has disappeared but logs are still coming when tomcat stops.